# How to use a header value inside an XML attribute using Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, akka-camel

I have the following in a camel route, but it doesn't seem to get the header value. Is this the right way to do it?

```
<to uri="ahc:http://${header.freeNasServerIp}:80/api/v1.0/storage/volume/"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this FAQ about dynamic to:
http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

---

See this link [How can I invoke a RESTful service through Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169570/how-can-i-invoke-a-restful-service-through-apache-camel)

Answer specific to this question is:

```
<recipientList>
<simple>ahc:http://${header.freeNasServerIp}:80/api/v1.0/storage/volume/</simple>
</recipientList>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it with XML rather than using Camel 2.16 and the toD tag?

Comment: Yes see the link again about recipientList